# Change MongoDB Collection from local to server-side on running Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Due to the [Meteor Docs](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#mongo-collections) there are 'server-side', 'client-side' and 'local' Collections. Is there a way to change the 'status' (e.g. if it's server-side, client-side or local) on a running app?

**Use Case:** A Web-Application where users can register and login. They can store sensible data. Depending on the  Users personal preferences he should be able to choose if that data is stored local or on the server (General decision - not from case to case).

**Current Approach:** It's working fine if I either instantiate the Collection local `CollectionName = new Mongo.Collection(null);` or server side `CollectionName = new Mongo.Collection('collectionName');`.
But I can't think of an approach to make it possible to the user that he can change the Collection status.

Is there a way to do this?
Or is a workaround needed (e.g. Create both, a local and server-side Collaction, and just decide which to use for insert/update/find - what would mean a lot of duplicate code?!).

**Edit:** To make thinks clear: I want the user to be able to choose if his data is stored in a collection which is synced with the server or a collection without any syncing.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the type of a collection on a running app.

I think you are confused about what these terms mean. "Client-side" collections aren't permanently stored in localstorage. It just means it's a collection that's **in the browser's memory**. Just as "server-side" collections are those that reside **in the server's memory**. The difference is not how it's defined, but where the code runs. Most collections have a client-side and a server-side counterpart, and they are kept synchronized via pub/sub. Server-side collections are also synchronized with MongoDB (using the oplog).

Local collections can live in both places, but "local" means they aren't synchronized with anything.

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but local collections do not persist data.

> If you pass null as the name, then you’re creating a local collection. It’s not synchronized anywhere; it’s just a local scratchpad that supports Mongo-style find, insert, update, and remove operations. (On both the client and the server, this scratchpad is implemented using Minimongo.)

This means any data added to them on the client will be blown away when the user closes their browser (unless you are also using one of the [local collection persist meteor packages](https://github.com/jeffmitchel/meteor-local-persist)) and any data added to them on the server will be blown away when the meteor app is restarted.  So I don't think you really want to use local collections.

Instead, I would use a regular collection (where a name is passed to the constructor) and either the standard [`allow`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-allow) or [`deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-deny) options ([not really recommended](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny) anymore...but still a valid approach) or Meteor methods (the preferred approach) to control who can change data and what data is allowed to change.

Or, another option could be to pass your publication function a list of fields that the user wishes to see on the client for that given session.  To do this you defined a new publication that receives a `displayFields` argument that you then use as the field specifier options in your collection `.find()`.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function (userId, displayFields) {
  // validate the structure and contents of displayFields

  // retrieve the data but only use the fields that the user requested
  return UserData.find({user_id: userId}, {fields: displayFields});
});
```

Then on the client side you would subscribe to this and pass in the fields the user wishes to make visible on the client.

```
var displayFields = {
  firstname: 1, 
  lastname: 0,
  //...
};

this.subscribe("userData", [displayFields]);
```

Comment: Please note that `allow/deny` rules are not recommended by the official [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny).

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention!  I personally never use `allow/deny` and always use Methods to implement collection data changes, but did not realize this was the official guidance.  I will update my answer accordingly to point this out.

Comment: I think you actually did not fully understand my question. But your answer helps me nevertheless, since [local collection persist meteor packages](https://github.com/jeffmitchel/meteor-local-persist) will probably help me to do what I want. I try to write my question up to clearify thinks.

Comment: Ok, cool. Want me to edit my question and just focus on persisting local collections then so it can be accepted?

Comment: ...would be nice.